# MariaDB create user using hostname

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created the following user, within the mariaDB USER table.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'dbadmin'@'example.ddns.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password_Here';
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON databaseName.* TO 'dbadmin'@'example.ddns.net';
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I then performed a host lookup on the server (running the mariaDB).

```
$ host engelsen.ddns.net
example.ddns.net has address 12.34.56.78
```

However, when I attempt to connect to the mySQL database (from the remote client), I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '12.34.56.78' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server.
```

Is there a reason why mariaDB (appears to be) incapable of performing a hostname lookup? Or is there a different reason why the access request is being rejected? Thanks!

Comment: Because the IP address is not resolved by mariadb